# iOS 11 : In App purchase error

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios11

We are getting in app purchase errors on iOS 11 using sandbox accounts.

following is the error 
NSConcreteNotification 0x1cc2560e0 {name = kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification; object = ; userInfo = {
transaction = "";
}}

Anyone please help if there is any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new sandbox accounts is what worked for me. Any accounts that I had created prior to iOS11 get stuck in a "Sign in/Create Apple id" alert loop.